# Installing python packages with script

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a python script that use additional libraries. I want to write a additional script for downloading these needed packages. That script will run by the user before run the actual script. I am using Linux environment and all packages downloaded with pip or sudo from command line. What is the proper way to do serve that kind of script? Is setup.py created for that purpose?

Comment: This is what `requirements.txt` is for: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files

Comment: If all dependencies can be satisfied with `pip` (doesn't necessarily have to be on pypi), then you can go with the `requirements.txt` as mentioned by Thomas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [Pypi](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files) way to do that, use `requirements.txt` file.

```
# requirements.txt
numpy==1.5.1
scipy==0.9.0
```

Then run:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

You can use `pip freeze` to get the currently installed packages.

```
pip freeze | grep numpy
# numpy==1.5.1
```

Comment: Thanks it works great :) Just for the curiosity, if we do this in requirements.txt file, why setup.py is not used for that purpose. What is its job?

Comment: `setup.py` is used to describe a python package and its dependencies (if you think your python script should be a package, use setup.py instead). Actually `pip install` runs `python setup.py install` for each package you specify in `requirements.txt` under the hood.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) In this situation, Am I have to a setup.py file that runs the requirements.txt?

Comment: No, the dependencies, in this case, are described in the `setup.py`.

There are [nice articles](https://caremad.io/posts/2013/07/setup-vs-requirement/#a-setuptools-misfeature) talking about the two methods